# JavaFX - Animation is not looping properly

Tags: java, animation, javafx

I am currently trying to make this Java animation loop: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/ColorfulCircles.java.html

To sum it up: The Programm creates circles, these circles wander from a generated Starting Point with the axes X and Y to a generated location, that also has a X and Y axes.
Now after they completed their path to reach the ending, a new loop in the while loop will start, but this time the circles will start at their last ending point(their new start Point) and only generate a new ending Point, so it looks like they wander from their past destination to another.

My Problem is that the coordinates are correct, but my circles spawn at the wrong location.
Here is a small output of my program:

```
//First loop with only 3 circles as example
0 StartX: 1110.2994232832264 StartY: 196.5353444146038
0 StartX: 1110.2994232832264 StartY: 196.5353444146038 EndeX: 77.09550167412587 EndeY: 781.9152623844685

1 StartX: 1026.967733288605 StartY: 228.60184379870438
1 StartX: 1026.967733288605 StartY: 228.60184379870438 EndeX: 1495.5868225131878 EndeY: 43.10288101605459

2 StartX: 909.8816160887294 StartY: 599.8395576620894
2 StartX: 909.8816160887294 StartY: 599.8395576620894 EndeX: 739.8188739717103 EndeY: 748.576558089626

3 StartX: 546.8538353648784 StartY: 211.33686550731284
3 StartX: 546.8538353648784 StartY: 211.33686550731284 EndeX: 465.06241304615554 EndeY: 676.2487115928532


//Second loop with the same 3 circles as before
0 StartX: 77.09550167412587 StartY: 781.9152623844685
0 StartX: 77.09550167412587 StartY: 781.9152623844685 EndeX: 609.5200149154447 EndeY: 600.3577965697156

1 StartX: 1495.5868225131878 StartY: 43.10288101605459
1 StartX: 1495.5868225131878 StartY: 43.10288101605459 EndeX: 727.4914318763049 EndeY: 609.0004943773514

2 StartX: 739.8188739717103 StartY: 748.576558089626
2 StartX: 739.8188739717103 StartY: 748.576558089626 EndeX: 435.20715512004284 EndeY: 491.23845197656414

3 StartX: 465.06241304615554 StartY: 676.2487115928532
3 StartX: 465.06241304615554 StartY: 676.2487115928532 EndeX: 1241.2695042799824 EndeY: 400.8279035402024
```

The Number at the beginning of each line is the identifier of the circle, StartX and StartY are the coordinates that these circles start from and EndeX and EndeY are the coordinates that these circles wander to.

As you can see Circle '0' stops at the Coordinates `EndeX: 77.09550167412587 EndeY: 781.9152623844685` and starts from the coordinates `0 StartX: 77.09550167412587 StartY: 781.9152623844685` in the next loop, so basically the animation should loop perfectly, but it does not, it appears that the circles still spawn at random locations...

Here is my starting class:

```
import static java.lang.Math.random;

import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.effect.BlendMode;
import javafx.scene.effect.BoxBlur;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.CycleMethod;
import javafx.scene.paint.LinearGradient;
import javafx.scene.paint.Stop;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.StrokeType;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Main extends Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }




    public static Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
    public static Group circles = new Group();
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1500, 850, Color.BLACK);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            Circle circle = new Circle(150, Color.web("white", 0.05));
            circle.setStrokeType(StrokeType.OUTSIDE);
            circle.setStroke(Color.web("white", 0.16));
            circle.setStrokeWidth(4);
            circles.getChildren().add(circle);
        }

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Random());
        Rectangle colors = new Rectangle(scene.getWidth(), scene.getHeight(),
            new LinearGradient(0f, 1f, 1f, 0f, true, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE, new Stop[]{
                new Stop(0, Color.web("#f8bd55")),
                new Stop(0.14, Color.web("#c0fe56")),
                new Stop(0.28, Color.web("#5dfbc1")),
                new Stop(0.43, Color.web("#64c2f8")),
                new Stop(0.57, Color.web("#be4af7")),
                new Stop(0.71, Color.web("#ed5fc2")),
                new Stop(0.85, Color.web("#ef504c")),
                new Stop(1, Color.web("#f2660f")),}));
    colors.widthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());
    colors.heightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());
    Group blendModeGroup =
            new Group(new Group(new Rectangle(scene.getWidth(), scene.getHeight(),
                 Color.BLACK), circles), colors);
    colors.setBlendMode(BlendMode.OVERLAY);
    root.getChildren().add(blendModeGroup);      
    circles.setEffect(new BoxBlur(10, 10, 3));

    t1.start();
    // play 40s of animation
    primaryStage.show();
}
}
```

and my class where I generate the circle movement in:

```
import static java.lang.Math.random;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Random implements Runnable
{

public void run()
{
    Main main = new Main();

    Double[] startingPositionX = new Double[15];
    Double[] startingPositionY = new Double[15];

    boolean firstRun = true;
        while(true)
        {

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e1)
            {
                System.out.println("Exception");
            }

            int i = 0;
        for (Node circle : main.circles.getChildren()) {

            Double startingPositionXNumber = 0.00;
            Double startingPositionYNumber = 0.00;

            if(firstRun)
            {
                startingPositionXNumber = random() * 1500;
                startingPositionYNumber = random() * 850;
            }
            else
            {
                startingPositionXNumber = startingPositionX[i];
                startingPositionYNumber = startingPositionY[i];

                System.out.println(i + " StartX: " + startingPositionXNumber + " StartY: " + startingPositionYNumber);
            }


            Double endingPositionXNumber = random() * 1500;
            Double endingPositionYNumber = random() * 850;

            main.timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, // set start position at 0
                    new KeyValue(circle.translateXProperty(), startingPositionXNumber),
                    new KeyValue(circle.translateYProperty(), startingPositionYNumber)),
                    new KeyFrame(new Duration(10000), // set end position at 10s
                    new KeyValue(circle.translateXProperty(), endingPositionXNumber),
                    new KeyValue(circle.translateYProperty(), endingPositionYNumber)));

            startingPositionX[i] = endingPositionXNumber;
            startingPositionY[i] = endingPositionYNumber;

            System.out.println(i + " StartX: " + startingPositionXNumber + " StartY: " + startingPositionYNumber + " EndeX: " + endingPositionXNumber + " EndeY: " + endingPositionYNumber);
            i++;
        }

        System.out.println("For each was completed.");
        firstRun = false;
        main.timeline.play();

        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Instead of using a `while` loop in another thread, just use an [`onFinished` handler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Animation.html#onFinishedProperty) on the timeline to restart it as soon as it finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the zero KeyFrame, with the starting values. I guess, there may be a problem. Your circles will start at the same position in the first run but don't worry it is just for debugging reasons.

```
main.timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(
                    new KeyFrame(new Duration(10000), // set end position at 10s
                    new KeyValue(circle.translateXProperty(), endingPositionXNumber),
                    new KeyValue(circle.translateYProperty(), endingPositionYNumber)));
```

Sadly i can't run your code right now (at work) but i can check later at home, if there wasn't a solution found.

Also your code is not save against reordering of the circles nodes in the `getChildren()` list. A better way would be to just use the `translateXProperty` (and Y) instead of the array. Because these properties are saving their last translation for you. (That's why, removing the zero KeyFrame should work)